# Is "here maps javascript api" supporting GeoJSON or any file format alternative to KML

Tags: kml, geojson, here-api

Is it possible to load GeoJson formatted data into here maps js api in a proper way? I am using AJAX to send data coming from mysql which is formatted in GeoJSON. I don't want to store any kml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no GeoJSON parser available directly in the **legacy 2.x** API, you will have to write your own. Since an external GeoJSON [parser library](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps/blob/master/GeoJSON.js) exists for the Google Maps API,  it is just a matter of replacing the Google Specific map objects with equivalent HERE Maps ones.

I've created a port based on the original, but keeping the HERE Maps Syntax [here](https://github.com/heremaps/examples/blob/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/geojson-parser/libs/geojson-parser.js)

The basic usage of the **GeoJSONContainer** is through the **parseGeoJSON()** method as follows:

```
function extend(B, A) {
    function I() {}
    I.prototype = A.prototype;
    B.prototype = new I();
    B.prototype.constructor = B;
}

function createGeoJsonParser(){
    extend(GeoJSONContainer, nokia.maps.map.Container);
    parser = new GeoJSONContainer();

}

function parseJson(jsonObject){

    result = parser.parseGeoJSON(jsonObject);   
    if (parser.state == "finished") {
        map.objects.addAll(result);
        map.set("center", map.objects.get(0).getBoundingBox().getCenter());

        map.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) {
            var text = JSON.stringify(evt.target.properties);
            bubble = infoBubbles.addBubble(text!== undefined ? 
                       text : "properties undefined",
                 evt.target.getBoundingBox().getCenter());
        }, false);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

see the link: [Simple geoJSON parsing](http://rawgithub.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/geojson-parser/parse-geojson-data.html)

Since **GeoJSONContainer** is an extension of **Container**, you could also add the geoJSON data directly onto the map using **addGeoJSON()**

```
var err = resultSet.addGeoJSON(jsonManager.object);
if (resultSet.state == "finished") {
    map.zoomTo(container.getBoundingBox());
    container.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) {
        infoBubbles.addBubble(evt.target.properties.Description,
         evt.target.getBoundingBox().getCenter());
    }, false);
} else {
    alert(err);
}
```

Basic Example Use: 
 - [Russia Provinces](http://rawgithub.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/geojson-parser/load-geojson-russia-data-using-ajax.html)

You can also add and style data points in the same manner as the **clustering** component

Styled Examples:

- [Football Teams](http://rawgithub.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/geojson-parser/load-geojson-premiership-data-using-ajax.html)
- [Hurricanes](http://rawgithub.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/geojson-parser/load-geojson-hurricane-data-using-ajax.html):

It comes with no guarantees of course.

For the **current 3.x** API, a geojson reader is included as standard you can refer to fxxxit's answer below:

```
var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('/path/to/geojson/file.json');
reader.parse();
//assuming that map already exists
map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a "new" version of the API which does allow you to get GeoJSON data directly (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.data.geojson.Reader.html)

```
var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('/path/to/geojson/file.json');
reader.parse();
//assuming that map already exists
map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

Comment: The link has changed: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-data-geojson-intro.html This is the official announcement: https://developer.here.com/news/102341#.VhKIRvm6eJA